# Why Twitter is unable to show my Hindi website links?

Tags: twitter, non-ascii-characters, unicode-string, social-media, twitter-share

i have a website in hindi language. When i try to share a post or page on twitter using social share button it shows strange on twitter something like this %E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE http://example.com/EgZw7 . Is there any way to fix it permanently?

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this on http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: `%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE` is the url-encoded form of the UTF-8 form of `क्या`.  This is how non-ASCII characters are supposed to look like in URLs.